# Pronunciation of "im" in prefix

Tags: prononciation

I've noticed that the prefix "im-" is sometimes pronounced as [ɛ̃], as in [immangeable](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/immangeable), but sometimes as [i], as in [immigration](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/immigration). Are there any useful ways to tell how the prefix should be pronounced in each word?